# Java: Proper way to resize SWT shell to maintain aspect ratio

Tags: java, linux, shell, resize, swt

I did see other threads here on SO this task. The recommended answer was pretty much what I implemented, see code below. The code works somewhat okay on Windows (head shaking a bit), but on CENTOS most of the time the application just locks. I assume that the application goes into an infinite loop or something.

My thought was to add a Java equivalent of C#.Net Application.DoEvents(), however I could not find how to do that and other threads here on SO consider that an improper solution and that time should be spent to implement a proper solution.

The problem on Windows is that when I resize the application, i see the brief outline / flash of the  application in the desired size that the user wants and then the final size that maintains the aspect ratio. I would prefer a clean with no jitter. I do need to support CENTOS (Linux), so hence my question here.

Here is the code fragment.

```
public class AppMain
{
    public Shell shell;
    public Display display;
    public ControlListener oShellControlListener;
    public Boolean isResizing = false;

    protected void createContents(Display display)
    {
        shell = new Shell(SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
        shell.setMinimumSize(new Point(660, 690));
        oShellControlListener = new ControlAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent arg0)
            {
                oAppEvents.eventAppResized();
            }
        };
        shell.addControlListener(oShellControlListener);

    }

    protected void eventAppResized()
    {
        // Do not allow multiple events.
        if (true == this.isResizing)
            return;
        else
        {
            this.isResizing = true;
            this.shell.removeControlListener(this.oShellControlListener);
        }

        // Get the new dimensions and the application minimum size (gives x/y ratio).
        Point sizApp = this.shell.getSize();
        Point sizAppMin = this.shell.getMinimumSize();

        // Make sure the user sizes the application while maintaining the same initial X/Y ratio. Y is limiting factor.
        int cxAppNew = (int)((double)sizApp.y * ((double)sizAppMin.x / (double)sizAppMin.y));
        if (sizApp.x != cxAppNew)
        {
            sizApp.x = cxAppNew;
            this.shell.setSize(sizApp);
        }

        // Allow another resize event.
        this.shell.addControlListener(this.oShellControlListener);
        this.isResizing = false;        
    }
}
```

Here are some links. The reason that I did not put links originally is that I am using the recommended solutions, namely using a static variable to prevent going back into the resize event and removing the control listener while resizing. Yes, the two approaches duplicate each other, so one or the other, but not both. When I get things working, I will clean things up.

[SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437563/correct-way-do-preserve-shell-aspect-ratio-in-swt)

[SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702296/java-proper-way-to-resize-swt-shell-to-maintain-aspect-ratio)

There were other articles, but I already closed my browser and could not find them again. The solutions were what I wrote: 1) variable 2) removeControlListener()

Comment: Can you provide the links to the other SO questions so we don't suggest the same solution again?

Comment: Looks like a tough one. Can't figure it out just now. Looking forward to a good answer here.

Comment: I updated the code to give the way that I actually implemented the resize. I thought using setSize() inside the event handler was obvious, but maybe not, so for completeness sake, here is the code. The other articles talked of the proportion, which I thought obvious, as how else? I agree Baz, this question looks like a hard one, but one that I thought should be a no-brainer. I have expected a shell.setAspectRatio(int, int) method, but I did not see any.

Comment: On Mac OS X holding the shift key while resizing a window with drag automatically maintains the aspect ratio but this seems to be an OS X feature rather than anything that SWT does.

Comment: I cannot comment on that in Windows, CentOS, or other Java supported platforms, but I will say that a user should not have to do that. Holding down the shift-key would be a non-obvious thing and not holding down the shift key would render the display distorted.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger I'm convinced you have your reasons for forcing a certain aspect ratio. But out of curiosity: What is it?

Comment: Microsoft Word and Notepad lend themselves to any aspect ratio, however my application has a zillion widgets, composites, and scaling fonts. I probably will have to allow any aspect ratio in the current GUI layout, however from previous debugging, any aspect ratio made the form look awful. Aside from that, this question is quite interesting. I would have to think for a moment, if Microsoft is any better in .Net. I would hope that C# is better on WinForms, but I am digressing and off topic. Hopefully, my answer will suffice, as you do not see the GUI.

Comment: Actually @Baz, I adjusted the fonts and with the minimum size, allowing whatever aspect ratio beyond that is not bad, so the question becomes an academic one.